# changing caption for wrapfigure

Tags: captions, labels

I am using wrapfigure to include both a table and a picture. However, because it's in wrapfigure, the table caption comes out labeled as "Figure X" rather than table x.

Is there any way I can get around this?

Thank you! Here's a snippet of my direct code!

```
\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Cluster  & Start & End & Muts. in Cluster & P-Value    \\ \hline
    1 & 751   & 858 & 4 & 1.35E-04 \\ 
    2 & 719   & 751 & 2 & 2.41E-03 \\ 
    3 & 790   & 858 & 2 & 2.82E-03 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{The three most significant clusters found in EGFR for the 2GS7 structure.}
\label{tab:EGFRClust}

\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{EGFRDrawing.eps}
\caption{The 2GS7 structure color coded by region: 1) cluster 1 - orange, 2) cluster 2 - blue and 3) cluster 3 - yellow. The boundary $\alpha$-carbon amino acids of 719, 751, 768, 790 and 858 are shown as purple spheres.}
\label{fig:EGFR-2GS7}
\end{wrapfigure}
```

Comment: use the capt-of package then `\captionof{table}{The three....} ` will give you a table caption.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion (as well as the answer below) worked great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`\captionof`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/%5Ccaptionof) command provided either by the [`capt-of`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/capt-of) or the [`caption`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/caption) packages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{wrapfigure}{l}{8.5cm}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|c|}
    \hline
    Cluster  & Start & End & Muts. in Cluster & P-Value    \\ \hline
    1 & 751   & 858 & 4 & 1.35E-04 \\ 
    2 & 719   & 751 & 2 & 2.41E-03 \\ 
    3 & 790   & 858 & 2 & 2.82E-03 \\
    \hline
\end{tabular}
\captionof{table}{The three most significant clusters found in EGFR for the 2GS7 structure.}
\label{tab:EGFRClust}

\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]{EGFRDrawing.eps}
\captionof{figure}{The 2GS7 structure color coded by region: 1) cluster 1 - orange, 2) cluster 2 - blue and 3) cluster 3 - yellow. The boundary $\alpha$-carbon amino acids of 719, 751, 768, 790 and 858 are shown as purple spheres.}
\label{fig:EGFR-2GS7}
\end{wrapfigure} 

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.

Comment: Hmm, when I try `\captionof{table}{tablecaption}` in my file in a wrapfigure below a tabular, I get 'Figure 1: tablecaption' as the output. When I put it at the top, I get an error: `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.`.

Comment: @equaeghe Almost impossible to detect the problem without the offending code. Feel free to open a new question with this issue, and make sure to provide there a MWE allowing to reproduce the problem mentioned.